# FFMPEG How to merge several videos to one file with fade effect and add audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

Need to merge several videos to one and add sound track mp3 file and last video with sound.

Only found this solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg
But uses static file length in parameters...

Ok, i can calculate all lengths before and add audio:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -i 1.mov -i 2.mov -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720 -filter_complex "[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va1]; [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[va2]; [3:v]scale=1280x720,trim=duration=9[over]; [over][va1]overlay[over1]; [over1][va2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" -vcodec libx264 -map 0:a -map [outv] -shortest out.mp4
```

How to merge more than two videos??
And how to add another end.avi which contains sound and mute music.mp3 ?

Comment: I've always manually set the exact locations of the fade effects when merging clips, but you need to be really careful and precise. It's a pain in the ass.

Maybe you could store the length values in internal variables `[0:0] st(variable_name, expression)`, then use these to calculate positions.

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy ok, basicaly i can first get file lengths and than generate parameters with exact locations. Ok, clear with it, how can i add audio to converted video?

Answer (score 1):

Using melt, simply and works as a charm:

```
melt *.MOV -mixer luma -mix 25 -track tmp.mp3 -consumer avformat:out.avi vcodec=libx264 b=5000k
```

But first need to cut mp3 file to overal video length, but that's not a problem:

```
ffmpeg -t LENGTH -i music.mp3 -acodec copy tmp.mp3
```